# Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration

Tags: centos, centos8, epel

I want to install MQTT but unable to install on CentOS 8 - Alibaba Cloud because I found following error

```
sudo yum -y install mosquitto
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:11 ago on Fri 03 Apr 2020 09:51:50 PM CST.
No match for argument: mosquitto
Error: Unable to find a match: mosquitto
```

Here's my EPEL list

```
 cat epel.*
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/Everything/$basearch
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-$releasever&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/debug
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-$releasever&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/Everything/SRPMS
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-$releasever&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: have you resolved this issue ?

Comment: Yes, by downgrading to CentOS 7. Mosquitto don't support on CentOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mosquitto do not support CentOS 8. So install on centos 7 and then install mosquito.